# How should angular services convey exceptions to controllers?

Tags: angularjs

I have a service which is basically a wrapper around some CRUD type operations.

```
app.service('fooService', function ($http) {

    this.getfoo = function(id) {
        return $http.get('api/foo/Get/' + id).then(function (result) {
            return result.data;
        });
    };

    this.getfoos = function () {
        return $http.get('api/foo/Get').then(function (result) {
            return result.data;
        });
    };

    this.createfoo = function(foo) {
        return $http.post('api/foo/Create', foo).then(function(result) {
            return result;
        });
    };

    this.updatefoo = function(id, foo) {
        return $http.put('api/foo/Update/' + foo.id, foo).then(function (result) {
            return result.status;
        });
    };

    this.deletefoo = function(id) {
        return $http.delete('api/foo/Delete/' + id).then(function (result) {
            return result.status;
        });
    };
});
```

What is the best way to handle exceptions? Is there a nice unit testable way to do this? I am guessing that the controller using this service shouldn't be aware that it is AJAX calls. Does that mean I need some standard way of communicating with services that act as datastores? Some object that I return with a success indicator and a message? E.g

```
var tmp = {
    success: false,
    error: 13,
    message: 'This foo already exists'
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should consider using Angular `$resource`.  It is way easier than all these `$http` calls: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource

Comment: You can handle global errors with $http interceptors. Did you try them? http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http (section Interceptors)

Comment: @BrianGenisio I have thought about that yes. But this CRUD type service is the exception rather than the rule. Most of the other screens are a little more involved.

Comment: @bekite Are you suggesting that I should try to standardize the return codes in my server side code. So primary key or unique violations should always return a certain status code and that gets dealt with in the HttpInteceptors? But then we can't change the way the error is displayed in the view easily. But that still leaves me with the questions of how should I let the controller something went wrong.

Comment: No, simply use the appropriate status codes to trigger the interceptors response and responseError methods and send back the error name and error message you want to display (error: { name: "user:create", message: "can't create user" } In the HttpInterceptor for responseError I would use an ErrorHandling service which uses pub/sub. The controller injects this service and can display the error. Maybe you could provide some more information on how you want to display errors in the view.

Comment: @bekite I am not entirely sure yet. Some places I think the controller would make use of a dialog service. Others it might update the form controller and its validation states. And I can see other controllers updating the scope's model so the view is updated. I was just under the impression that the controllers shouldn't be getting the HttpResult with the status codes and headers and data payloads. This seems like a leaky abstraction to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$http.delete('api/foo/Get/' + id)` returns promise therefore we can use Error handler like:

```
app.service('fooService', function ($http) {

 var tmp = {
           success: false,
           error: -1,
           message: ''
           }

    this.getfoo = function(id) {
        return $http.get('api/foo/Get/' + id).then(function (result) {
            return result.data;
        }, function (result) {
            tmp.message = "blablblab";
            tmp.error = result.status;
            return tmp;
        });
    };
    ....
});
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/672/)</kbd>

Comment: Sorry I think my question might be misleading. I know that. But we wouldn't want to show alerts from the service right? Alert is a GUI thing. I also don't want to return the http promise itself because then the controller has to know about HTTP status codes.

Answer (score 0):

To start with your service methods can return promise object. Since a promise get resolved to a success or failure you would know when action completed and when it failed. Remember promise can used for any call of async nature. They are not tied to AJAX call only.

As a first step your service methods should return the promise directly when using $http service.

```
 this.getfoo = function(id) {
        return $http.get('api/foo/Get/' + id);
    };
```

In your case you are returning `then` function return value. As the documentation mentions

> This method returns a new promise which is resolved or rejected via
>   the return value of the successCallback, errorCallback. It also
>   notifies via the return value of the notifyCallback method. The
>   promise can not be resolved or rejected from the notifyCallback
>   method.

you are suppressing the error that you get from server, because you did not add a error callback function. So better do `return $http.get(...)`. This way you can handle the success and error case in the controller or any other place like

If you want to wrap the errors into specific object you can create you own promise in the service and return custom on promise rejection.